# Sending new objects to template

Tags: django

Is it possible to add new objects to my template without re-loading the page?

Similar to AJAX call, based on the URL, I could update the objects without a refresh or re-direct? For example `{{ foo }}` would be a place holder, and I could update server side what object `{{ foo }}` point to.

Comment: What do you mean, "similar to AJAX call"? You would do this *using* an AJAX call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I only know how to return JSON from ajax call. How do I return new objects so I can use the django template language

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, template rendering in django is conduct on the server side. To do client side DOM manipulation, you will need to use a javascript library.

Angularjs / knockoutjs  / Jquery are good libraries to look at.